# fail to dockerize the second kafka instance to zookeeper

Tags: docker, apache-kafka

I want to dockerize a kafka cluster with two kafka instances.

running zookeeper

```
docker run -it --name zookeeper -p 2181:2181 -p 2888:2888 -p 3888:3888 debezium/zookeeper
```

running kafka

```
docker run -it --name kafka -p 9092:9092 -e ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME=$(hostname -f) --link zookeeper:zookeeper debezium/kafka
```

running one zookeeper and one kafka is successful but adding the second kafka container shown as below

```
docker run -it --name kafka2 -p 9096:9092 -e ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME=$(hostname -f) --link zookeeper:zookeeper debezium/kafka
```

gives me the following error:

```
2019-09-24 04:11:48,728 - ERROR [main:Logging@74] - Error while creating ephemeral at /brokers/ids/1, node already exists and owner '72057611679825940' does not match current session '72057611679825967'
2019-09-24 04:11:48,748 - ERROR [main:MarkerIgnoringBase@159] - [KafkaServer id=1] Fatal error during KafkaServer startup. Prepare to shutdown
org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$NodeExistsException: KeeperErrorCode = NodeExists
    at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:122)
    at kafka.zk.KafkaZkClient$CheckedEphemeral.getAfterNodeExists(KafkaZkClient.scala:1784)
    at kafka.zk.KafkaZkClient$CheckedEphemeral.create(KafkaZkClient.scala:1722)
    at kafka.zk.KafkaZkClient.checkedEphemeralCreate(KafkaZkClient.scala:1689)
    at kafka.zk.KafkaZkClient.registerBroker(KafkaZkClient.scala:97)
    at kafka.server.KafkaServer.startup(KafkaServer.scala:260)
    at kafka.server.KafkaServerStartable.startup(KafkaServerStartable.scala:38)
    at kafka.Kafka$.main(Kafka.scala:75)
    at kafka.Kafka.main(Kafka.scala)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the debezium Kafka container, you need to pass `-e BROKER_ID=2`. The default is 1.

https://github.com/debezium/docker-images/blob/master/kafka/0.10/docker-entrypoint.sh#L6-L9

---

In other Kafka containers, there's a `KAFKA_BROKER_ID` variable you can use that needs to be different for each container that also sets up replication factors to 2 for internal topics and correctly sets up the advertised listeners.

Here's an example compose file

```
---
version: '2'
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:latest
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000

  kafka-1:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:latest
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    ports:
      - 19092:19092
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_HOST:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:19092,PLAINTEXT://kafka-1:9092
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 2
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 2

  kafka-2:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:latest
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    ports:
      - 29092:29092
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 2
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_HOST:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:29092,PLAINTEXT://kafka-2:9092
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 2
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 2
```

Ex.

```
$ kafkacat -L -b localhost:19092
Metadata for all topics (from broker 1: localhost:19092/1):
 2 brokers:
  broker 2 at localhost:29092
  broker 1 at localhost:19092 (controller)
 1 topics:
  topic "__confluent.support.metrics" with 1 partitions:
    partition 0, leader 1, replicas: 1,2, isrs: 1,2
```

Note: running multiple brokers on one machine won't improve any performance or reliability of Kafka

Comment: docker run -it --name kafka2 -p 9096:9092 -e ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME=$(hostname -f) --link zookeeper:zookeeper -e KAFKA_BROKER_ID=2 confluentinc/cp-kafka  doesn't work either. it says KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT is required.
Command [/usr/local/bin/dub ensure KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT] FAILED !

Comment: Yes, you need `-e KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=zookeeper:2181` with confluent container. Debezium container automatically adds that one, and `ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME` is renamed to `KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS`, which takes both a hostname and a port (otherwise, `-p 9096:9092` won't work, and the container is still advertising to connect by 9092)... I suggest you just use the existing Docker compose examples https://github.com/confluentinc/examples/blob/5.3.1-post/cp-all-in-one/docker-compose.yml#L1-L35